# is the patent US20140253038 still valid and in force

Tags: us20140253038

I would like to know if the patent is still valid because I have the same type of 
invention I want to patent

Comment: The linked document is a patent application and not yet a granted patent. It may or may not get granted. That said, it would still represent prior art to your invention. You would have to demonstrate something novel over what is described on this application and all other prior art to obtain your own patent.

Answer (score 1):

Eric's answer was concise, I'm just adding onto it and presenting an answer instead of a comment.
So the document with the publication number:[US20140253038A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20140253038) is a **Utility patent application**. It has been **Abandoned** -- *Failure to Respond to an Office Action*, the status recorded on **03-07-2016**. This patent application was never granted. But since it's application was published, if you have a similar invention you will have to consider it as a prior art for your invention and show non-obviousness and novelty over the existing prior art.

So to answer your question, the patent application is **no longer valid** *(Abandoned)* but its claims will still restrict the grant of your invention unless your invention can prove its novelty.

Comment: Good answer. Thanks for taking the extra step of checking the application's status.

Comment: My pleasure, nice to have you as a member of the site.

Comment: @leegroves If you find this answer acceptable  (and in my opinion you should), it would be great if you could accept it by clicking the check mark.